# What information can an Android App tell about other apps on a phone?

Tags: android

If I had an app that wanted to assess what other apps I had on my phone and make recommendations for new ones, what information can I read off the phone and send back to our server?

Comment: What information do you want to read?

Answer (score 2):

Try PackageManager: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

Answer (score 0):

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        final List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(   mainIntent, 0);
```